# onFocus event.which is always 0

Tags: javascript, html, focus, contenteditable

I want to tab in to an content editable div and do something, for that i am using `onFocus="(arguments[0].keyCode ? arguments[0].keyCode : arguments[0].which) === 9"`, the problem is, that arguments[0].which/keyCode is always 0, (should be 9 for tab)

Any Ideas what to do?

(yes this just got marked as a duplicate, but it isnt (at least for the linked duplicate))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `onFocus` event is not the same than a `key-action` event, so it doesn't carry that information. You can try another approach, like listening for `keyup` events on your document and then checking if your element has focus after it. Here is a working example with 2 inputs, you can try tabbing into the second one.

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', evt => {
  if ((evt.keyCode ? evt.keyCode : evt.which) === 9 && document.querySelector('#input2:focus')) {
    console.log('I WAS TABBED INTO')
  }
})
```

```html
<input name="asd">
<input id="input2">
```